# List in footnote in list

Tags: footnotes, enumerate, itemize

It appears that LaTeX treats lists in a footnote differently when the `\footnote`
command appears in a list itself. Cf. the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Text.\footnote{Text.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This is an item.
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an item.\footnote{Text.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This should be an item, but it looks like a subitem.
  \end{enumerate}
}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a subitem.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

A workaround would be to split the footnote in the list into `\footnotemark` and
`\footnotetext` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Text.\footnote{Text.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This is an item.
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an item.\footnotemark
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a subitem.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\footnotetext{Text.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This should be an item, and it is one.
  \end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

This, however, is both tedious and error-prone, in particular if a page break
falls between the `\footnotemark` and the `\footnotetext`, moving the footnote to
the wrong page.

Is there a better solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Footnotes are formatted inside saveboxes at the footnote location, so they inherit the `\@listdepth` and `\@enumdepth` count values at the time.  This redefines `\footnote` to reset those counts to zero (whether they are used or not}.  One might even consider this a bug fix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\oldfootnote=\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[2][\empty]% #1 = number, optional, #2 = text
{\ifx\empty#1\relax \oldfootnote{\@listdepth=0 \@enumdepth=0 #2}%
 \else  \oldfootnote[#1]{\@listdepth=0 \@enumdepth=0 #2}%
 \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text.\footnote{Text.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This is an item.
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an item.\footnote{Text.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This should be an item, but it looks like a subitem.
  \end{enumerate}
}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a subitem.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]