# How to align sentences in footnote

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes, alignment

How to align multiple sentences vertically in one footnote? For example, in the screenshot below I need to make the three texts and their numbers aligned vertically:

[image: As in this screenshot i need to make the three texts and their numbers aligned vertically]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}

\begin{document}

This is some examples\footnote{\label{subtypes examples}  1 - text\\ 2 - text\\  3 - text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try \parbox, tabular or enumerate.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354710/list-in-footnote-in-list.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting a screenshot from your editor, please add the code of your minimal document (which is good) directly to the question. You can format code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon when editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy hack:

The LaTeX standard classes (and the `extsizes` classes) use a box of `1.8 em` to typeset the footnote number, and a paragraph indentation of `1 em`. You can change the paragraph indentation to the same `1.8 em`:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is some example text\footnote{\label{subtypes examples}%
\parindent1.8em
1 -- Text\par
2 -- Text\par
3 -- Text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx, that was helpful

Comment: But what was the function of the percentage sign because it didn't work without it.
excuse me i'm newbie

Comment: @Maged Because TeX treats single line breaks as spaces. Try typing a sentence with a line break (enter key) instead of a space; the printed output will be the same (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407620/134574) for a more detailed explanation). If you don't put a `%` there, the line break is treated as a space, which is inserted before the `1 --`, thus the misalignment. The `%` there is what we call a "end of line protection" and it basically comments the line break so TeX doesn't understand it as a space.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you really want a list, then I would use a proper enumerate structure. Here I've defined a new enumerate list `fnenum` which aligns with the footnote number.

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{fnenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[fnenum]{label={\arabic*~--~},before=\vspace{-\baselineskip},nosep,labelsep=0pt}
\begin{document}

This is some examples\footnote{\label{subtypes examples}
\begin{fnenum}
\item An item
\item Another item
\item A third
\end{fnenum}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thx, that was more advanced method

Comment: @Maged One of the strengths of LaTeX is automation. So you should almost never number things by hand.